# Setting minOccurs and maxOccurs in XSD based on value of other XML field?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an XSD to validate an XML file. The structure is as follows:

```
<root>
    <child>
        <size>2</size>
        <childElement>Element 1</childElement>
        <childElement>Element 2</childElement>
    </child>
</root>
```

The number of `childElement`s is dependent on the size provided i.e. if `size` was set as 3, not more than 3 `childElement`s can be added.

I have tried using `xs:alternative` but it does not seem to work:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="child" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="size" type="xs:integer" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="childElement" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1">
                                <xs:alternative test="@size>1" maxOccurs="@size"/>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Is there a way of using `xs:alternative` or another tag to achieve this, or is this outside the realm of possibility with XSD?

Comment: Really interesting use case. I've never seen anything like it though. You'd need to do validation in your parser I think

Comment: @DavidBrossard: True for XSD 1.0; for XSD 1.1, `xs:assert` [**would work**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40488337/290085).

Answer (score 4):

**Design recommendation**: If your XML design can still be changed, eliminate the `size` element and convey that information implicitly rather than explicitly.  By eliminating the duplication of information, you'll not need to check that the duplication is consistent.

If your XML design cannot still be changed, or if you choose not to change it...

### XSD 1.0

Not possible.  Would have to be checked out-of-band wrt XSD.

### XSD 1.1

Possible using `xs:assert`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="child">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="size" type="xs:integer"/>
              <xs:element name="childElement" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert test="count(childElement) = size"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```