# XSD field dependent on another field

Tags: xsd, dependencies

I have a XSD with two fields - one is a status enum of `ACCEPTED` or `REJECTED` and the other one is the rejected_note that should be filled only if the status is rejected.

Something like this:

```
           |----Rejected_Note----|
Status     minOccurs     maxOccurs
ACCEPTED   0             0
REJECTED   1             1
```

How can I set `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` according `Status` value?

the relevant xsd sections:

```
<xs:element name="approval_status">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="APPROVED" />
            <xs:enumeration value="REJECTED" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="reject_reason" type="xs:string"
    minOccurs="???" maxOccurs="???">
</xs:element>
```

Comment: See [***Setting minOccurs and maxOccurs in XSD based on value of other XML field?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487452/setting-minoccurs-and-maxoccurs-in-xsd-based-on-value-of-other-xml-field)

Comment: @kjhughes, Thank you very much !!