# XML Schema - Dynamic maxOccurs?

Tags: xml

I'm wondering if it could be possible to refer the maxOccurs property value of an element to the value of another element.
For example in this case:

```
<xs:complexType name="X">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="maxNumberOfY" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
    <xs:element name="Y" maxOccurs="?" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

the number of Y elements should not exceed the value of the element "maxNumberOfY". Is there any solution?

Comment: I would also love to see an answer to this.

Comment: this is a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487452/setting-minoccurs-and-maxoccurs-in-xsd-based-on-value-of-other-xml-field